# Word Association in text mining

Tags: natural-language, text-mining, word2vec

I want to extract the information from text on the basis of association like. "Shahrukh Khan is the Famous actor of Bollywood, his wife name is Gauri khan. He is 52 years old. Sample output like as

```
Name: Shahrukh Khan
age: 52
wife: Gauri Khan
```

and so on which method should i use.
I am able to extract to name by nlp but what method should i use for next(is RNN is good)?

Comment: Try a regex or fuzzy matching. The age is always a number and in most cases it consists of two digits.

Comment: @Ferdi Thanks for your support, but what if it contains 52 as well as 32, 34, 21 also and what for wife name and others.